# fstream - cannot access private members declared in class basic_fstream<_Elem, _Traits>

Tags: c++, ios, iostream, fstream

I use `fstream` to open a file for writing purpose.

```
fstream streamFile;  
streamFile.open ( "C:\\path\\to\\textFile.txt", 
fstream::in | fstream::out| fstream::app);
```

I get the following error:

```
cannot access private members declared in class basic_fstream<_Elem, _Traits>
```

What is missing?

Comment: Works for me, can you add more code?

Comment: This is the whole code. What is the trigger for this kind of error? Did you encounter it?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, and also if there are more messages when building then please show all of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream streamFile;
    streamFile.open("C:\\Robin\\input.txt",
        fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
    if (streamFile.is_open())
    {
        streamFile << "Hej" << endl;
        streamFile.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my entire code, it works and does not trigger any error. It creates or appends to the .txt-file in the given directory. No proplems. Compare to this and see if anything difers.

Comment: Thanks. The error refers to the class fstream, at this code: `private:
_Myfb _Filebuffer;};`. Any ideas?

Comment: I have to say like @Joachim Pileborg, "Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and show us, and also if there are more messages when building then please show all of them".